# Dimensions of perspective function in R

Tags: r, perspective

I am trying to figure out a 3D graph where the z values are a lot

I would like the graph to look like this

[image: Image 1]

but currently the graph looks like this

[image: Image 2]

I understand the shape has to be more rectangular because of the large data in the z matrix, and I have tried changing different parameters, how will I change this

This is the current code I have

```
persp(Tester, c(1:25), as.matrix(yielder2[-1]), 
      phi = 45, theta = 20000000000, col = "red", ltheta = -135, lphi = 0,
      shade = 0.5, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Time to maturity", zlab = "yield", box = TRUE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-scale the data you put in and set `scale = FALSE` otherwise the axes are all scaled to 1:

```r
persp(lubridate::yday(yield$Date) * 2, 1:13, as.matrix(yield[-1] * 5), 
      phi = 30, theta = 120, col = "gray95", ltheta = 40, lphi= 10, shade = 0.5,
      scale = FALSE, zlab = "yield", xlab = "date", ylab = "Time to maturity")
```

[image]